# Attempting to write a prepared statement in python

Tags: python, sql, prepared-statement

I understand that this question has been asked before but for different languages, however I'm a bit unsure how exactly it needs to be done. When looking for examples online I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

My code currently consisted of the following when I found it:

PYTHON:

```
  with open('converted-drop-copy-sample-data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
# execute a statement
    for row in reader:
        for x in range(10):
        # insert method
            row = [None if x=='' else x for x in row]
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO messages (column 1, column 2, column 3)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (row))
            conn.commit()
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing the second part of the code, to which I need to set all the parameters at the end, but I'm not too sure how to go about that or even if that is the next correct step, any help?

Comment: Sorry, that was a comment, let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of you are using MySql, it would be:

Assuming a line read from the csv file consists of `1,2,3`

```
row = tuple(line.split(','))
cur.execute("INSERT INTO messages (column 1, column 2, column 3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", row)
```

For details:
[MySql Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)